# Tomcat one port only for one WAR

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I have two WAR file running in my tomcat 6 server.

How can i set each WAR listen to only one port?
For example:

port 443 => only can access a.war

port 8000 => only can access b.war

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to configure the above scenario using these settings: I created two folders named *443* and *8000* under the *webapp* folder, and configured two Service-elements pointing to two different folders and listening on two different ports.

server.xml

```
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="8000" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/.keystore" keystorePass="xxxxx"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/8000"
         unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
         xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
            <Context path="" docBase="Apple"/>
  </Host>
</Engine></Service>

<Service name="Catalina2">
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />

<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/.keystore" keystorePass="xxxxx"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

<Engine name="Catalina2" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps/443"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
  </Host>
</Engine></Service>
```